# Creating forms in Django with multiple Many-to-Many fields in Models

Tags: python, django

I have these three models with two many to many fields in BlogPost models like

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and form on client side as follow

```
{% extends 'blog_project/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}
    <div class='login-container'>
        <h2 class='login-heading'> Create New Post </h2>
        <form class='login-form' method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div class="form-group pb-3">
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {{ field|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class='form-group'>
                <button type = 'submit'>Post</button>
                <a href="{% url 'blog:blog_list' %}">Go Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
{% endblock%}
```

it allows me to select from the existing categories but not allows to add other categories.

I want to create a form in django that allows a user to select from the categories on client side as well as create new categories or tags and save them to the database so that other users can selects from these or search them atleast.

Comment: What do you mean? Normally if you press Ctrl and click extra items, you can select multiple ones.

Comment: I am asking about the Django forms, not the computer files.

Comment: it's not about computer files, it acts the same way in a HTML form...

Answer (score 0):

For that, you will need to manually render a field the user can enter the name of the Category they want to create. You can the access the entered value in your view, save it to the database, and add it to the Blog Post object.

Inside your HTML form tag, include:

```
<input type="text" name="new-category">
```

Then in your view, you can access and save the entered value:

```
def add_blog(request) :
    ... 
    new_category = request.GET("new-category")
    if new_category:
        category = Category.objects.create(name=new_category)
    ... 
    # if you want to immediately add the new category to the instance of a BlogPost
    blog_post = blog_post_form.save() 
    blog_post.categories.add(category)
```